# Should we use short or long tags for regional/country tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I've seen people using `united-states` and `usa`, similarly I've seen `uk` and wouldn't be surprised to see `united-kingdom` pop up. We should probably decide on one or the other and then just set tag synonyms to streamline that process.

(See also: [Regional tagging rules?](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/regional-tagging-rules) - discussion of when and how these tags should be used; a separate question from this one.)

Comment: @dcaswell I referenced what I believe you're referring to in my question - the other post seemed to be asking more about *when* and *why* to tag things as regional, not how. I think they are both important but separate discussions.

Comment: I notice [hf] vs [high-frequency], which is the same issue for a different set of tags.

Comment: @KevinReid True, though in that case I'd probably be in favor of going with the acronyms, since they tend to be more frequently used compared to the long versions (not to mention it's clearer that they're referring to the radio wave band, and not to a general descriptor).

Comment: (And when I say "more frequently used" I mean in common lay-person usage, not just jargon.)

Comment: completed for [tag:us] -> [tag:united-states] and [tag:uk] -> [tag:united-kingdom]

Comment: Older discussion but thought I should point out that this becomes even more important when you start mixing in single phrase country names like "Canada" and "Mexico" where the 2-letter ISO abbreviations would be "CA" and "MX". In the case of Canada the abbreviation often gets misunderstood by American's to mean "California" (a 2 letter abbreviation for a state/region/province, not a country). All this to say I also believe full region and country names are most appropriate when tagging for both human readability and search indexing.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I'm inclined to favor long tags - e.g. [united-states](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states). It's more readable, especially when placed along with other tags. Short tags tend to wind up as an alphabet soup.